# spring boot runtime error with org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheServletWebConfiguration.mustacheViewResolver

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am a beginner for spring boot.

I build my spring boot project with maven3.6.3 and java11.0.13 successfully.

But error occurs when I try to run it.

Here is my Application.java file

```java
package com.chohotech.doctorservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DoctorServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(DoctorServiceApplication.class, args);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The full stack trace is showed below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheServletWebConfiguration.mustacheViewResolver
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
        at com.chohotech.doctorservice.DoctorServiceApplication.main(DoctorServiceApplication.java:11)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:487)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:436)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheServletWebConfiguration.mustacheViewResolver
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:517)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:506)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:429)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/view/AbstractTemplateViewResolver
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.resolve(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.getReturnType(OnBeanCondition.java:525)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:513)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateViewResolver
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 45 more
```

I build it with command line and my commands are

```
$ mvnw clean install
$ java -jar target/Service-0.0.1.jar
```

And my pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.chohotech.doctorservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>DoctorService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>DoctorService</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.chohotech.doctorservice</groupId>
            <artifactId>com-chohotech-doctorservice-model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.samskivert</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmustache</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- check style-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.spring.javaformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-javaformat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.29</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>validate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- spot bugs-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- coverage report-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>coverage-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>coverage-report</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Threshold -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>coverage-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>CLASS</element>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>com.chohotech.doctorservice.DoctorServiceApplication</exclude>
                                        <exclude>com.chohotech.doctorservice.DoctorServiceController</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0%</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't known how to solve it and I am wandering for help, thank you.

Comment: You are either not using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to build the jar or you are mixing modules from different versions of the framework. In short without seeing your `pom.xml` this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: You are excluding mustache which Spring seems to complain about. Have you tried not excluding?

Comment: I tried not excluding but it did not work.